# IdeaVim / PyCharm mis-handles 0 key

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, pycharm, ideavim

Have an issue where any time I use my zero key in Normal mode it moves the cursor to the beginning of the line. This is the correct functionality when I simply hit 0, but not when I'm in the middle of other commands.

For instance:

10j (move cursor down 10 lines)

d40G (delete everything between cursor and line 40 below)

120k (move cursor up 120 lines)

Each of these moves my cursor to the beginning of the line I'm on as soon as I hit the 0.

Comment: File an issue in the project's bug tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is described in [VIM-700](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-700).